# lstlisting inside itemization

Tags: itemize, lstlisting

I need to have \lstlisting inside an itemization. I have the following code but as you will see from the output, the listing starts on the line following the item label. Is there anyway to get it on the same line (I thought I had asked this before or read it before, but I can't seem to find it -- so my apologies if this is a repeat):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=SQL,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    deletekeywords={DOMAIN}, 
    morekeywords={*,IF,DEFINE,OPTIONS, SERVER, MENTIONS, IN, CONTAINS, ANCHOR}, mathescape=true,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    belowskip=6pt,
    literate={SUCH\ THAT}{\bfseries SUCH\ THAT}{9}
}

\newcounter{exlcal}
\newenvironment{exalist}{\begin{list}{\bf
            (\alph{exlcal})}{\topsep 10pt\partopsep 0pt \labelwidth 12pt\labelsep
            12pt\leftmargin 24pt
            \itemsep 0pt\usecounter{exlcal}}}{\end{list}\addvspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    Do the following:
    \begin{exalist}
        \item \begin{lstlisting}
        SELECT B, COUNT(C)
        FROM   R
        GROUP BYB
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{exalist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to obtain your output. The result I got was exactly what you are looking for. I did run it with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: The listing also starts on the same line as `(a)` for me, but there's a spurious space right before `SELECT`

Comment: That is strange. This was produced on a Mac using MacTex 2019 using pdflatex. I wonder if the distribution makes a difference. Don't know where to go from here, but many thanks.

Comment: Just an update to close the case -- I ran texlive to update everything and then recompiled and it works right now except as @siracusa noted, there is a spurious space before SELECT, but I can live with that.